# Planck's law - energy, frequency and temperature dependancy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermal-radiation

Unlike radio waves, thermal radiations are emitted at a broad range of frequencies. So, at a given temperature, an object might be emitting a lot of frequencies. Is that correct?

So ehen Planck's law says energy is proportional to frequency, does it mean energy of each frequency that is emitted and it is applicable for all frequencies that are being emitted?

Also, I have seen linear graphs between energy and temperature at constant frequency.

How can you keep frequency constant when you increase the temperature? Shouldn't the frequencies should change?

Answer (score 1):

> Unlike radio waves, thermal radiations are emitted at a broad range of frequencies. So, at a given temperature, an object might be emitting a lot of frequencies. Is that correct?

Yes, a blackbody emits electromagnetic radiation with different frequencies at a specific temperature.

> So when Planck's law says energy is proportional to frequency, does it mean energy of each frequency that is emitted and it is applicable for all frequencies that are being emitted?

For this question my answer would also be yes. Planck's law states that the radiance of a body per unit frequency can be determined in terms of density of Fourier modes of the emitted radiation and the average energy of a mode which can be written as;
$$
B(f,T)=\frac{2hf^3}{c^2}\frac1{e^\frac{hf}{k_BT}-1}
$$
where $\frac{2hf^3}{c^2}$ is the number of modes per unit frequency per unit volume, $\frac1{e^\frac{hf}{k_BT}-1}$ is the average energy of a mode, and $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant. Overall, this expression can give us the spectral radiance of an electromagnetic radiation wave at a specific frequency emitted from a body at a specific temperature.

To calculate the radiance of the body(density of total energy of the electromagnetic radiation with all frequencies a body can emit at a certain temperature), we must integrate the above expression;
$$
\int B(f)df=\int\frac{2hf^3}{c^2}\frac1{e^\frac{hf}{k_BT}-1}df
$$

Before Planck's law, according to the [equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem) in classical physics, the average energy of a mode was $k_BT$ and all modes had equal energy. This led to a false prediction that the emitted energy would increase continuously to infinity with the frequency(ultraviolet catastrophe). Therefore, quantum physics, more specifically Planck's law, showed that the energy of a mode would be $\frac1{e^\frac{hf}{k_BT}-1}$ which stated that the probability of a mode with higher energy to exist is lower than the probability of a mode with lower energy. All in all, Planck's law matched better with experimental results.

If you want to check the credibility of these expressions, you can match the experimental data in this graph with the mathematical data you will get from above expressions:
[image]

TL;DR: The answers to your first and second question are yes and yes. As for your third question, different bodies at different temperature can emit radiation with the same wavelength. Therefore, as the temperature of a body increases, the body can still continue to emit a wave with the same frequency but the probability of that emitted wave would be lower.